# is there a way to filter files by name in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to filter files by name in VS Code?  The search icon in the left nav pane provides the ability to do a global text search within the directory context but I haven't seen a way offhand to search for specific files.  For example, let's say I want to search for "Chart.component.tsx" or find all test files in the project by searching for ".test.tsx".  Is there any way to go about doing this in VS Code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type `ctrl-P` then start typing the file name.  VSCode will search the directories for you.

Comment: thanks!  also available via top menu @ Go > Go To File

Answer (score 1):

You can highlight or limit the files that match a find on **file name** in the Explorer using:

[Advanced tree navigation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_advanced-tree-navigation)

With the **Filter** button you can limit the files shown that match.

The **Filter** button has a new look compared to the documentation and they have added a **Fuzzy Match** option.